# Windows 8 Nav Window Feature on Mac

Tags: windows, macos, navigation

In windows 8, I think this started in Vista actually, if you drag a nav window to the top bar of the screen, it auto expands and maxamizes to fit the screen.  If you drag it away, it shrinks to the original size.

As far as I've tinkered, I haven't been able to get this feature on my mac.  Does anyone know of a method or a download that can create the same or a similar effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several utilities for that functionality, for example

BetterSnapTool
https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12

Cinch
http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/

Moom
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moom/id419330170?mt=12

I used cinch for quite a while, but the others seems to work fine too, moom can do more window management.